# How to shut down Fedora without logging in

Tags: fedora, login, shutdown

I have Fedora 27, and when I go away, the login screen is shown.
Then I return to shut down the PC, but is not allowed to shutdown the PC from the login screen. I need to log in and then shut down.

Is there a way to enable direct shut down (power off) from the login screen? (It has a power button, but it doesn't allows shutting down)

[image: Link to image]

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams it doesn't have the option for shut down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not answer your question, but.

If you switch to the `gdm` login screen, the power button there works.

To switch to the gdm login screen, press Ctrl+Alt+F1, or click "Log in as another user".  If you use a multi-seat system, the former will only work on the first seat.  And I'm not sure if the latter is available if you only have one user (as shown in the gdm login screen).

I checked this on Fedora 28 (I think it works the same way in Debian 9 as well).

You might find it more convenient to do this all without using the mouse/touchpad etc.  To shut down in gdm (or GNOME), you can press Ctrl+Alt+Del and then Enter.

Alternatively you can press Ctrl+Alt+F6 to switch to a text console, and then press the power button.  In this case, you will *not* get any warning about the list of user login sessions, or other registered shutdown inhibitors.  (If for some strange reason you wanted to reboot instead, you could use Ctrl+Alt+Del instead of the power button).

Comment: That is the `gdm` lock screen, actually. Fedora uses Gnome and `gdm` by default.

Comment: @Mioriin edited. I don't know exactly how it works. I think my instructions are unambiguous enough. But maybe this is a bit clearer if I describe it as the login screen.

Comment: It would be quicker to just unlock the session and shutdown from there. Your method also has the inherent risk of losing unsaved changes to `~/thesis/final/masterpi.ece` in the active session.

Comment: @Mioriin yes, I wouldn't recommend it as a habit (you are welcome to edit that in). I read your answer and wanted to be explicit that Gnome or Fedora are only trying to prevent accidental data loss. I guess another way to look at it is that when shutting down from gdm, you are warned with the list of current (non-gdm) sessions. If you shut down from the lock screen of a given session... you would probably want it to do the exact same thing i.e. include the session the lock screen belongs to in the warning list, but it seems a special case and a bit weird.

Answer (score 2):

Fedora does not automatically log you out of the system if you walk away from it.
It is, however, set by default to lock your screen after few minutes idle.
The screen you see is the lock screen interface, which does not have a system shutdown function to prevent data loss by someone walking in and shutting down your machine while you were out for coffee.

Simply unlock the screen with your password to return to the active login session, where you can make sure you don't have open files that you don't want to lose, before shutting down the system.